# Can't delete first row

Tags: javascript

```
<table id="tableID">
    <tr>
        <th>Attr</th>
    <th>Val</th>
</tr>
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="firstChk" />
</td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="firstAttr" />
</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="firstVal" />
</td>
</table>

<input type="button" value="Add A Row" onclick="javascript: addARow('tableID')" />
<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="javascript: deleteARow('tableID')" />
```

This separate js file gets called:

```
function deleteARow(tID) {
try {
    var tableObj = document.getElementById(tID);
    var numRows = tableObj.rows.length;

    // starts at 1 because never delete row that holds table headers
    for(var index=1; index < numRows; index++) {
        var rowObj = tableObj.rows[index];
    // rowObj.cells[0] gives the td, then childNodes[0] gives checkbox element
        var chkboxObj = rowObj.cells[0].childNodes[0];

            if(null != chkboxObj && true == chkboxObj.checked) {
            tableObj.deleteRow(index);
                /* next 2 lines are necessary because DOM's tr indices shift back
                 * with a deletion
                 */
                numRows--;
                index--;
        }
    } // end for
} // end try
catch(e) {
    alert(e);
}
} // end function
```

This code can delete any row and any number of rows after clicking the "Delete" button EXCEPT for the first row that has a checkbox(the one whose xpath is //table/tr[1]).  I've traced through the code by hand multple times and have been unable to debug it, so I've posted the code with my comments.

What's wrong with the code?  I wish I could figure out how to use the js debugger in firebug :(

Comment: var rowObj = tableObj.rows[i];//where is this "i" from?

Comment: FYI, your HTML code is invalid inside your `table` tag.

Comment: You might have better luck if you use the `<tbody>` and `<thead>` tags

Comment: You're starting at index `1`, not `0`? It is also easier if you loop downwards on things like this

Comment: When I try debugging, chkboxObj.checked is undefined.  How does your very first row differ in creation than the others?  Perhaps the way you create your second+ row is creating the checkbox a different way?

Comment: You only have one table row (you need to wrap what you want to be the second row in `<tr></tr>`); you're using `[i]` but you define `index`, so you should use that. I'd start there.

Comment: 1.  sorry, i meant to type index.  <br>
2.  I'm starting at 1 because I don't want to touch the first row, it holds the table headers.  
3.  The html inside the table tag is fine, it displays perfectly the second row/first row with a checkbox.  
4.  The first row with a checkbox is different from the other checkboxed rows in that it was hand typed html, not html generated by the javascript.

When I add a bunch of rows and delete the last 2 rows, chkBoxObj.checked is true, so they are deleted.  If you're seeing that for the first row with a checkbox, why is that happenening?

Comment: @HukeLau_DABA, the HTML displays fine because browsers are smart. With that being said, you have `td`'s that don't belong to any `tr`'s. That not cool :)

Comment: @James Hill and clrockwell: sorry bro now I see.  Everything works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few issues with your code.

First, the markup for your table was malformed. You have `td`'s without parent `tr`'s.

Second, the logic that you used to get the checkbox object was not returning the checkbox. So, when you hit your `if` statement, `chkboxObj.checked` returned `undefined`.

Here's the updated/working code:

**HTML**

```
<table id="tableID">
    <tr>
        <th>Attr</th>
        <th>Val</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="firstChk" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="firstAttr" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="firstVal" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Add A Row" onclick="addARow('tableID')" />
<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteARow('tableID')" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
function deleteARow(tID) {
    try {
        var tableObj = document.getElementById(tID);
        var numRows = tableObj.rows.length;

        // starts at 1 because never delete row that holds table headers
        for (var index = 1; index < numRows; index++) {
            var rowObj = tableObj.rows[index];

            // rowObj.cells[0] gives the td, then childNodes[0] gives checkbox element
            // This was not returning the checkbox element. See updated code:

            // Get first input in row - this will be the checkbox
            var chkboxObj = rowObj.cells[0].getElementsByTagName("input")[0];

            if (chkboxObj != null && chkboxObj.checked == true) {
                tableObj.deleteRow(index);
                /* next 2 lines are necessary because DOM's tr indices shift back
                 * with a deletion
                 */
                numRows--;
                index--;
            }
        } // end for
    } // end try
    catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
} // end function
```

Also, here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DMuxp/1/).